# 3x3 real matrices with same minimal polynomial but different jordan normal form

Tags: matrices, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

This is to show that the minimal polynomial does not determine the jordan normal form. I've tried a few but haven't got anywhere.

Why is this marked as duplicate? The other post does not give me an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the minimal polynomial $(X - 1)(X - 2)$?